# In Django, is it possible to use reverse/redirect with a view function (not string) as a to parameter, when using namespaces?

Tags: django

I'm trying to get `reverse` (via `redirect`) to work in the context of *namespaces* and when using view functions.
This fails with a `NoReverseMatch`, somewhat to my surprise. In principle, I'd say that it's out-figurable in an automatic way what I mean.
When using this without `app_name = ...` this works fine.
Is this a bug (or simply unsupported)? Or is there a way it could be made to work?

```
# urls.py

from django.urls import path

from .views import some_other_view, some_view

app_name = 'foo_app'  # here the app namespace is defined
urlpatterns = [
    path('some_other_view/', some_other_view),
    path('some_view/', some_view),
    # ...
]


# views.py

from django.shortcuts import redirect


def some_other_view(request):
    return redirect(some_view)  # note that the view is simply passed as a function here, not as a string.


def some_view(request):
    # ... actual view here
```

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Comment: You are right: if there is an `.app_name`, they only append it to the namespace: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/urls/resolvers.py#L562 but this thus means that the view does not end up in the reverse dictionary.

Comment: This fast patch should fix the problem https://gist.github.com/KommuSoft/892a8de1e52851bbfddc4c6f10981476 , but whether it is sound and complete is of course a different question :). The resolver is a "nice christmas tree"...

Comment: made a ticket on https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/35244 and pull request https://github.com/django/django/pull/17896

Answer (score 2):

It is unsupported. It is explained in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) explicitly saying using reverse with a callable is discouraged as `reverse` can't be used with namespaced views.

```py
# using the named URL
reverse("news-archive")

# passing a callable object
# (This is discouraged because you can't reverse namespaced views this way.)
from news import views

reverse(views.archive)
```